# Javascript to get form name

Tags: javascript

I need to get the value of the form name. In this example "basic_form":

```
<form name="basic_form" method="post" action="/">
```

Tried this but it doesnt work:

```
function() {

var element=document.querySelector('form[name]').textContent;

return element;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about [getAttribute()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp)

```
return element.getAttribute("name");
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function demo() {

var element=document.getElementById("myForm").name;
document.getElementById("get-name").innerHTML=element;

}
```

```css
#get-name{
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form name="basic_form" id="myForm"  method="post" action="/">
<p onclick="demo();" id="get-name">Click here to get form name</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `getAttribute`

```
var element=document.querySelector('form[name]').getAttribute("name");
```

Here is the working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QLdJW/470/